# C# Remove Phone Number from String?

Tags: c#, regex, string

How do i remove phone number in following format from a string?

xxx-xxxxxxx or xxx-xxx-xxxx or xxxxxxxxxx

where x is any number.

Comment: Your requirement is not clear!!!

Comment: there are many ways........ first try something, if not got any solution then add your code here.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question and provide us more details. Thanks.

Comment: What are the rules? Looks like there are no rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help:

```
var myRegex = new Regex(@"((\d){3}-1234567)|((\d){3}\-(\d){3}\-4567)|((\d){3}1234567)");
string newStringWithoutPhoneNumbers =  myRegex.Replace("oldStringWithPhoneNumbers", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Ok i figured how to do it with this example. Thanks!